# I have to convert utc time to ist in excel

Tags: excel, utc

I have to convert utc time to ist time in my excel the the time format is 10:00:00 utc this has to converted in IST timing.
Please suggested

Comment: Just add(or subtract) the time needed: `=A1 + Time(8,0,0)` where 8 would be the number of hours to add.

Comment: So in this case, `=A1+Time(5,30,0)`, or `=A1+5.5/24`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no inbuilt functions that identify/convert the timezones. We can extend the capabilities of Excel **Time()** function to solve this use case.

```
=A1+Time(5,30,0)
```

For **IST**, you will have to ***add 5 hours and 30 minutes***. Similarly, you can convert to any timezone by adding/subtracting the time difference.

The three inputs given to the **Time()** are ***hours,minutes and seconds***.

This function returns the timestamp in a serial number format. Excel will interpret this number and show the timestamp in a readable format.